# WordPress can't display uploaded images (3.6)

Tags: linux, wordpress, image-uploading

I'm having a bit of trouble with a client site, on their server (our development server is fine).

We were hoping to push it live today, so we created a test subdomain to make sure his server's okay with the site.

However, the media uploader doesn't seem to work properly. The file will upload, without any error messages, however, instead of displaying the image in the thumbnail preview, it shows a little blue `?`.

The file is actually uploaded to the server, but for some reason it can't be displayed online.

For example [this should be the location of a newly upload image](http://b9.seeyourselfonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/tiesto3.jpg), but for some reason it can't be accessed.

I was thinking the issue is with folder permissions, but changing everything to 777 didn't seem to do anything. So I'm a little confused as to what's wrong.

Apparently they host a couple dozen WordPress sites and don't have this issue. I did think it's a server problem because it works on two other servers.

Anyone had an issue like this before?

[EDIT]

It turns out deactivating a plugin called Sell Media Watermark does the trick.

However, this plugin is needed so I'm working to find a fix for it :)

Comment: When I click that link, it redirects to a plugin's URL (http://seeyourself.b9media.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/sell-media-watermark/watermark.php?image=2013/08/tiesto3.jpg) - does it work if you disable the plugin?

Comment: Well, given that your URL redirects to `http://seeyourself.b9media.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/sell-media-watermark/watermark.php?image=2013/08/tiesto3.jpg`, it looks like the problem's to do with the Sell Media Watermark plugin that you seem to be using. Is it possibly a configuration issue with the plugin, or perhaps a .htaccess rule for the plugin that you've not successfully transferred to the new site?

Comment: Hmm, deactivating the watermark plugin does the trick! Now to find out why it breaks :/